# Dead wife haunting her husband's new wife

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

So I remember seeing a movie about a guy who got married very fast and moved into a house with his new wife and then strange things started happening. The cat drowned in the bathtub. There was hair in the wife's hairbrush that wasn't hers and it turned out the guy had an ex- wife who died, then the current wife found the ex-wife's diary and there were new entries every day.

Not sure about the country but I believe the language was English. The movie was made for TV. It looked like it was released sometime in the 90's. I saw it on TV in 2007, so it can't be anything released after that year. It's definitely not *The Grudge*, *What Lies Beneath* or *Shutter* both the re-make and the original Asian version.

I don't remember much, but I'd appreciate if you could help.

Comment: Country\language? Approximate year of release? And are you sure it's not *The Grudge*? (A lot of similar themes there)

Comment: Not sure about the country but i believe the language was English. It looked like it was released sometime in the 90's.  It's definitely not The Grudge.

Comment: I was thinking _What Lies Beneath_ but not that much of it matches

Comment: Trish, it's not _What Lies Beneath_ either :(

Comment: @Irenass Do you remember the time period the *plot* took place in? Was it modern times?

Comment: Modern times! I saw it on TV in 2007, so it can't be anything released after that year.

Comment: OK, thanks. Added that too. (Well, it seems they lifted that hairbrush bit from *The Tomb of Ligeia*...)

Comment: You said you saw on tv, was it originally a theatrical release or a made-for-tv movie? Any idea of the channel?

Comment: The movie was made for TV and I was abroad at the moment so the channel is irrelevant..

Comment: @Neil it's not _Hide and Seek_. It wasn't up until the middle of the movie when it was revealed that the guy was married before. He kept his previous marriage and the death of his wife a secret from his new wife.

Comment: Sadly it's not Shutter either. I don't remember the who the actor was but it definitely wasn't Joshua Jackson.

Comment: @Irenass: The [original version of *Shutter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_%282004_film%29) doesn't have Joshua Jackson in it.

Comment: The movie that comes to mind is Rebecca. It's really good.

Answer (score 3):

The movie is called [*The Intruder (1999)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187995/?ref_=ttkw_kw_tt) with Charlotte Gainsbourg and Nastassja Kinski. From an [online review](http://variety.com/1999/film/reviews/the-intruder-4-1200459309/):

> Catherine [...] meets soundtrack composer Nick Girard (Charles Powell) at a gallery opening, and in no time they’re wed and she moves into his gorgeous loft-apartment. Nick doesn’t talk about [his previous wife] Stella, but Catherine learns she was found dead clutching a large pair of scissors amid signs of a fierce struggle. [...]
>
> Despite its cutting-edge decor, the building is old, with a sinister handyman and electricity that often fails, requiring the use of candles and flashlights. Catherine starts noticing strange things around the house — a glass of wine with tell-tale lipstick, a brush with strands of someone else’s hair, a crooked painting, an unexplained reflection and, finally, a diary with the initials “SG.”

Comment: Better to add the title in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There was one I saw called Shutter. Same theme, about a photographer woman, but I'm not too sure about the smaller details